# How to show that $P_n(x)$ have n distinct roots

Tags: polynomials

Let $P_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ , $n\in \mathbb N$ be defined by

$P_n(x)=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2^n n!}\frac{\displaystyle d^n}{\displaystyle dx^n}[(x^2-1)^n]$
I need to show that $P_n(x)$ has exactly $n$ distinct roots in $(-1,1)$
I think it is important to use induction and Rolle's theorem.

To use induction, $P_1(x)=x$ and it is trivial that the root is $x=0$ in $(-1,1)$
, but the inductivity is problem. 
I assumed that $P_n(x)$ has $n$ distinct roots, and yet I can't advance further.

Comment: Try binomial theorem.

Comment: How to utilize binomial theorem? Please just give me a piece of hint

Comment: If you proof that your polynomials are orthogonal you could use this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527140/proof-the-legendre-polynomial-p-n-has-n-distinct-real-zeros/528150#528150

Comment: For a proof based on Rolle's theorem, see my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/748203/59379) to a similar question.

Comment: Ah! It was Legendre polynomial! I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a statement about $\frac{\displaystyle d^k}{\displaystyle dx^k}[(x^2-1)^n]$, i.e. show by induction on $k$ that $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are roots of multiplicity $n-k$ and tehre are $k$ simple roots in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more details about the part of using Roll's Thereom in your proof?